# Trouble writing clojure spec for a schema

Tags: clojure, specifications

I have a schema of following structure

```
{:active? true|false
 :metric 90
 ....
}
```

The semantics here is that if `:active?` is false, then `:metric` should have a value of `0`

Yes I can do the following

```
(s/keys :req-un [::active? ::metric] verify-structure) ;; verify-structure will test the above logic
```

But this doesn't help me with test data generation as its possible verify-structure can fail for all the generated data.

I guess I'll have to build a custom generator but I'm not sure how to generate dependent fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify a custom generator like this:

```
(require '[clojure.test.check.generators :as gen])

(gen/let [active? gen/boolean
          metric (if active? (s/gen int?) (gen/return 0))]
  {:active? active? :metric metric})

(gen/sample *1)
({:active? true, :metric 0} {:active? true, :metric -1} ...)
```

`gen/let` is a macro that lets you use a familiar `let`-like syntax, but it expands to test.check `fmap` and `bind` calls which you could also use directly.

Once you have your custom generator, you can use `s/with-gen` to combine it with your spec, or pass it in an *overrides* map to spec functions that take generator overrides.

Comment: This is great. Thanks!